# Is Informix-SQL supported under Open SuSE?

Tags: informix, suse

Is Informix-SQL supported under Open SuSE or under Novell's SuSE Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISQL is supported on Novell's SuSE Enterprise (and Redhat Enterprise Linux, RHEL), but there's no obvious reason why it would fail on the Open SuSE edition - unless you know of some incompatibility between the two variants of SuSE.

Comment: Ok.. What's the latest version of ISQL for SuSE?.. Does the latest version work with IDS, SE or both?

Comment: As far as I know, ISQL 7.50.xC5 is available.  It will work with SE and IDS 11.x.